# Exception statement not covered by self.assertRaises in python unit test cases

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertraises

This is my function:

```
def get_value(request, param):
  s = get_string(request, param)
  value = re.search('(\\d\\d\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d)', s)
  if not value:
    print 'match not found!'  
    raise Exception('incorrect format: %s' % param)
```

test function:

```
def test_get_value(self):
    m = test_mocks.HttpRequestMock(REQUEST = {'start_date': '2011.07.31'})
    print '*************************'
    print 'date format changed'
    self.assertRaises(Exception, get_value, (m, 'start_date'))
    print '*********************
```

`get_value` doesn't print: *match not found*!

Comment: Your `helpers.get_date_param` calls `get_value`?

Comment: changed the call... i had modified the function name for posting the question here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there is some issue with your python version. I guess you are using python below version 2.6.
Try passing function parameters as other arguments to function i.e. do not put them inside tuple. Try this.

```
self.assertRaises(Exception, helpers.get_value, m, 'start_date')
```

Answer (score 5):

You're passing the arguments to `assertRaises()` incorrectly, you should pass them like this:

```
self.assertRaises(Exception, helpers.get_value, m, 'start_date')
```

Here's a full test case that works for me. The first test passes, and the second one fails.

```
import re
from unittest import TestCase

def get_value(s):
    value = re.search('(\\d\\d\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d)', s)
    if not value:
        raise ValueError('incorrect format: %s' % s)

class TesterScratch(TestCase):
    # this one passes
    def test_get_value(self):
        s = '2011.07.31'
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, get_value, s)

    # this one fails, because the format is actually correct
    def test_get_value2(self):
        s = '2011-07-31'
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, get_value, s)
```